# Type of regression for large dataset, nonlinear, skewed in R

Tags: r, statistics, bioinformatics, non-linear-regression

I'm researching moth biomass in different biotopes, and I want to find a model that estimates the biomass. I have measured the length and width of the forewing, abdomen and thorax of 37088 specimens, and I have weighed them individually (dried).

First, I wanted to a simple linear regression of each variable on the biomass. The problem is, none of the assumptions are met. The data is not linear, biomass (and some variables) don't follow a normal distribution, there is heteroskedasticity, and a lot of outliers. Now I have tried to transform my data using log, x^2, 1/x, and boxcox, but none of them actually helped. I have also tried Thiel-Sen regression (not possible because of too much data) and Siegel regression (biomass is not a vector). Is there some other form of non-parametric or median-based regression that I can try? Because I am really out of ideas.

Here is a frequency histogram for biomass:
[Frequency histogram dry biomass](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p38uX.png)

So what I actually want to do is to build a model that accurately estimates the dry biomass, based on the measurements I performed. I have a power function (Rogers et al.) that is general for all insects, but there is a significant difference between this estimate and what I actually weighed. Therefore, I just want to build to build a model with all significant variables. I am not very familiar with power functions, but maybe it is possible to build one myself? Can anyone recommend a method? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is really a cross-validated question rather than R programming. Note that you can run linear regression without meeting the assumption of normality (for example, people often do this for a binary dependent variable; see Mostly Harmless Econometrics for why this might be OK). Your standard errors will be wrong, but your estimate will still minimize the mean squared error. If you're into prediction, that's all you need.

Answer (score 0):

To fit a power function, you could perhaps try nlsLM from the minpack.lm package

```r
library(minpack.lm)
m <- nlsLM( y ~ a*x^b, data=your.data.here )
```

Then see if it performs satisfactory.